# Using TFLite for streaming LSTM inference with multiple LSTMs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to port an LSTM model over to TFLite, where my LSTM layers are running at different speeds due to intermediate pooling:

```
Conv1d(kernel_size=5)
Pool(2)
LSTM()
Conv1d(kernel_size=5)
Pool(2)
LSTM()
```

This LSTM model is used for streaming inference from audio, where the first layer is getting chunks of size N. Each LSTM needs to maintain its own hidden state and only perform a forward pass and forward its results to the next layer when it has a full buffer (kernel size of convolution + 1 for pool). For example:

```
T=6: 6 frames of audio
LSTM1 forward -> lstm1_t0
LSTM1 hidden_state -> new_hidden_state
LSTM2 buffer: [lstm1_t0]
T=8:
LSTM1 forward -> lstm1_t1
LSTM1 hidden_state -> new_hidden_state
LSTM2 buffer: [lstm1_t0, lstm1_t1]
...
T=16
LSTM1 forward -> lstm1_t5
LSTM1 hidden_state -> new_hidden_state
LSTM2 buffer: [lstm1_t0, ..., lstm1_t5] <- length 6
LSTM2 forward -> lstm2_t0
LSTM2 hidden_state -> new_hidden_state
LSTM2 buffer: [lstm1_t1, ..., lstm1_t5] <- length 5
```

I would ideally like to accomplish this with one TFLite model, where the easiest abstraction I can think of is the original (TF1) session objects, where I would simply sess.run([]) with the necessary tensors. Is anything like this possible in TFLite? Otherwise, it seems like I have to export a .tflite model for each  conv/pool/LSTM block and manage them as individual models.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem before?

Thanks!